# Input datepicker - block dates for all months

Tags: c#, input, datepicker

I see how to set specific blackout dates, but is there a (easy) way to set blocked dates for all months?

Scenario - a user may select a start date for a periodic process, but will only be allowed to select one (usually, might be two or three) day in a month.  So they may select to start in July, August, September, etc, but it may only be the (example) 24th of the month.

Further complication - That date (range) will change based on certain parameters - I'll retrieve that date via a process.

Yes, I found myself wondering if it even makes sense to use the datepicker if it's only one day, but they would like to keep the design the same.

I suspect it's doable, but no idea what combination of command will allow it.

Comment: You tagged your post as C# but didn't explicitly tell, so to clarify: are you using Xamarin Android?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the default one, use the `Material DateTime Picker` ([Java](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) | [Xamarin Android](https://github.com/Plac3hold3r/PH.Wdullaer.Materialdatetimepicker)) instead of the default one.

With the `setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days)` method you can declare which days can be selected. Just retrieve the available dates from the server or whatever the source is and update the calendar accordingly by the above call.
There is also `setDisabledDays(Calendar[] days)` to disable days instead.

Of course, on Xamarin Android, you have to use `SetSelectableDays(Java.Util.Calendar[] days)` and `SetDisabledDays(Java.Util.Calendar[] days)` instead.